# Transparent BSDF with a sine wave

Tags: rendering, shaders, transparency, osl

I'm making a light mask setup which should be giving me a sine wave of transparency, which would then yield the projected light to be a sine wave.
I'm using 2 transparency shaders, one set to fully transparent and the other set to fully black and blending them with a factor which varies with X position such that we should be getting sinusoidal waves of light. When I render, save, and plot using ImageJ, I can see that the light profile is not sinusoidal.
1- the light source is a point
2- the transparency shader is sin( 2pi * x )/2 + 0.5

The surface is white.

Is there something I'm missing? am I using the right shaders? are there parameters of the shaders I neglected?

The shape of the light seems to be more biased toward the bright part of the sinusoidal and having a pointier dark part.

```
shader circlefade(
point Vector = P,
float size = 0.5,
output float Fac = 0.0)
{
    float f = 100;
    float phase = 0*3.1416/2;
    float r = sin(phase+(Vector[0]*2*3.1416*f))/2+0.5; // sine is in Radians
    Fac = r;
}
```

[image]

Edit: I found that it was actually because under "Color Management", I had the camera set to Film which makes the exposure have these strange effects. When setting to "standard", we no longer have the uneven sinusoidal

Comment: If you're after exact values, have you saved the image as OpenEXR for scene linear values?